# Secure GWT application with https

Tags: gwt, https, jetty

I am developing a GWT web application, now I want to secure the whole web application via HTTPS. Aanybody has an idea?

I am using Jetty web server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do anything specific to GWT for enabling Https. 
Just [enable the ssl as usual](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html), and access your GWT host page using an https url.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reverse-proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/%20nginx).

This example of nginx configuration would do this :

```
server {
  listen   443;
  server_name  my.https.srv;

  ssl  on;
  ssl_certificate  /etc/certs/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/certs/cert.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my.jetty.srv:8080/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the different parts of your config?