# GWT - How to use HTTPS

Tags: java, http, gwt, https

For school I need to make a little and simple WebApplication:
I thought of creating a little very simple GWT Application where the User can enter a Nickname and a Password to get access to the site.

Behind my server there is a database with information about the students and one with the username/password. We are supposed to secure the database with CaesarCypher.

If I remeber correctly RPC-calls to the server are HTTP but the tasks asks for HTTPS communication.

How can I use HTTPS in my Application and what do I need to do to implement it?
I only started with the tasks and only made some sketches and generated the sample code from GWT.

Thanks in advance for any tipps or recommendations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure GWT application with https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161121/secure-gwt-application-with-https) and/or [Run gwt with https enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791758/run-gwt-with-https-enabled) and/or [How to enable HTTPS in GWT's Jetty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370919/how-to-enable-https-in-gwts-jetty).

Comment: addtional to @Jon Sampson comment: you cannot enable https with superdev mode. If you want to debug local you have to disbale https and turn it on in production